# SEAndroid-Run an app in a specific security domain

Tags: android, security, selinux

I have an app (service) that does not have an activity. I would like to start this app in init.rc like this:

```
service secret_service /system/bin/am startservice com.my.secret.service/com.my.secret.service.SecretService
    class late_start
    user root
    group root
```

If run like above, this service runs in the "platform_app" security context. Howerver, I would like to run this in a different security context, such as "mysecurity". I have already tried using the seclabel like this:

```
service secret_service /system/bin/am startservice com.my.secret.service/com.my.secret.service.SecretService
    class late_start
    user root
    group root
    seclabel u:r:mysecurity:s0
```

But it does not work. Does anyone have an idea how to achieve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should make an entry in [`mac_permissions.xml`](http://selinuxproject.org/page/NB_SEforAndroid_2#mac_permissions.xml), which maps the app signing certificate to an `seinfo` value, and a corresponding entry in [`seapp_contexts`](http://selinuxproject.org/page/NB_SEforAndroid_2#seapp_contexts), which maps the `seinfo` value to a domain.  Also, if your domain isn't one of the standard ones, then you also have create the appropriate type enforcement file (e.g., `mysecurity.te`) in `external/sepolicy` for inclusion at policy build time.